# GameObject.Find not working on Player in DontDestroyOnLoad

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet, unity3d-mirror

The Player Object with script `GamePlayerManager` is set up by the `NetworkLobbyManager` when creating the GameScene after Lobby using

```
var conn = RoomPlayers[i].connectionToClient;
var gameplayerInstance = Instantiate(gamePlayerPrefab);
gameplayerInstance.SetDisplayName(RoomPlayers[i].DisplayName);
gameplayerInstance.SetPosition(RoomPlayers[i].Position);
NetworkServer.Destroy(conn.identity.gameObject);
NetworkServer.ReplacePlayerForConnection(conn, gameplayerInstance.gameObject);
```

In `OnStartClient` on the `GamePlayerManager` i try to Reference a `GameObjects` with `myHand = GameObject.Find("myHand");` but myHand is null afterwards.
My Hierarchy in this moment: [Hieracrchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciA60.png)

Doesn't it work because the Player is in DontDestroyOnLoad?
And I heard that .Find isn't the best option to find reference, but what is?

Answer (score 0):

Now i found that OnStartClient is called to early for the scene to exist, used the Find methodes right before the transform change and it worked